# Name that function property

Tags: analysis, functions

I am encountering functions of real variable with the following property:
$$ f(x) = f(1/x) $$
For example,
$$ f(x) = \left(x - \frac{1}{x}\right)\log^{3}{x} \qquad x > 0 $$
Is there a name for this property?

Comment: "Symmetric with respect to reciprocation" is how I would call it

Comment: Invariant under inversion

Comment: This is an observation, not a name. If the domain of $f$ consists of positive numbers, then $g(t) = f(e^t)$ is symmetric about the origin.

Comment: @SrivatsanNarayanan:  I think you mean $f(e^t)$ is symmetric across the $y$ axis.

Comment: @Shaun Ah, yes. You are correct. I thought of it as a function, rather than as a graph on 2-D. In any case, it might be best to say "$g(t)$ is an even function".

Answer (score 2):

Summary of comments:

- "Invariant under inversion" is a good name for such functions
- If the domain consists of positive numbers, one can say instead "$t\mapsto f(e^t)$ is even".